# How can we change where Anaconda creates environments?

Tags: python, anaconda

By default, when you create a virtual environment with `conda create`, the files are written to a subdirectory off the user's home: `~\.conda\envs\<name>`.

What we would like to do is specify a shared directory for all users, outside of home. The [docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html) seem to indicate this is possible (*"Where conda lists known environments"*), but I can't find the config argument or any example.

Thanks!

Comment: I know you can specify a custom directory during install. You might want to just run the Miniconda installer again and choose the directory during installation. You can uninstall your original by simply deleting the entire installation directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guh - I think I found it [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/central.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs). If I'm reading it correctly...